# Join table if table has results

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a few tables

1. clubs -> contains information on different clubs
2. clubs-leagues -> contains information about different leagues hosted by the clubs
3. codes -> contains description of short hand codes ive used to make data entry a little easier

clubs-leagues has a field that contains the id of the clubs to form an association with eachother.

i have the following statement

```
SELECT club.*, sport.name AS sport, code.description AS statusText,
    code1.description AS ageGroup, code2.description AS gender,
    leagues.name AS leagueName, leagues.ageGroup AS age, leagues.division,
    code3.description AS leagueGender, leagues.season
FROM clubs as club
JOIN sports AS sport ON sport.id = club.sport
JOIN codes AS code ON club.status = code.code
JOIN codes AS code1 ON code1.code = club.ageGroup
JOIN codes AS code2 ON code2.code = club.gender
JOIN `clubs-leagues` AS leagues ON leagues.clubId = club.id
JOIN codes AS code3 ON leagues.gender = code3.code
WHERE club.id=(:n)
```

it works if the club has a league but if there is no leagues (club-leagues table) then it returns no results(i want it to show the results from the club table even if there is none in the clubs-leagues table)

currently i have tried moving"JOIN `clubs-leagues` AS leagues ON leagues.clubId = club.id " up right after i declare clubs AS club and using a left join but i got no resuls

thanks

Comment: You should use `LEFT JOIN` if you want to see results with no records in the joining one

Comment: I've removed the PHP, since it's basically irrelevant to the question - your question is about querying and sql, and PHP is merely the delivery vehicle.

Comment: `JOIN` requires a match, where `LEFT JOIN`/`RIGHT JOIN` will return even if there is not match. see also http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in comments, you need to use `LEFT JOIN` from clubs to leagues to get all clubs regardless of league membership.  Your SQL could look like this:

```
SELECT club.*, sport.name AS sport, code.description AS statusText,
    code1.description AS ageGroup, code2.description AS gender,
    leagues.name AS leagueName, leagues.ageGroup AS age, leagues.division,
    code3.description AS leagueGender, leagues.season
FROM clubs as club
LEFT JOIN `clubs-leagues` AS leagues ON leagues.clubId = club.id
JOIN sports AS sport ON sport.id = club.sport
JOIN codes AS code ON club.status = code.code
JOIN codes AS code1 ON code1.code = club.ageGroup
JOIN codes AS code2 ON code2.code = club.gender
JOIN codes AS code3 ON leagues.gender = code3.code
WHERE club.id=(:n)
```

Note that I haven't checked the rest of the SQL, it's up to you to ensure it's correct.

Comment: i needed to add left join on `JOIN codes AS code3 ON leagues.gender = code3.code`

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` or `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` for including all values from left|right tables, even if right|left tables have not matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM clubs as club
LEFT JOIN `clubs-leagues` AS leagues ON leagues.clubId = club.id
--LEFT JOIN sports AS sport ON sport.id = club.sport
--LEFT JOIN codes AS code ON club.status = code.code
--LEFT JOIN codes AS code1 ON code1.code = club.ageGroup
--LEFT JOIN codes AS code2 ON code2.code = club.gender
--LEFT JOIN codes AS code3 ON leagues.gender = code3.code
```

Since I do not know what data you have or if there may be a hidden issue with it , I would recommend this approach.  Run the query above and when you get the results comment in the next line and refine your query as you see the results and know you are getting all you require.  Then you can limit your select statement and add the where clause.
  Also be careful on the Where clauses, they can wreak havoc on left joins if not carefully used.